# How to make python module installer for windows?

Tags: python, windows, installation

How to make python module installer for windows?

I have python (2.7 if that makes difference) module which wrapped functionality around C-lib and would like to make an installer with build lib to make installation easy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using distutils, you can write a setup file that would compile your libs and install them

- http://docs.python.org/library/distutils.html
- http://docs.python.org/distutils/index.html#distutils-index

See this example setup.py which also compiles "c" lib for different platforms.

- http://code.google.com/p/psutil/source/browse/trunk/setup.py